# Existence of solution to a advection-reaction equation with forcing term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, nonlinear-analysis, hyperbolic-equations

Consider the advection-reaction equation in One-Dimension

$\dfrac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \dfrac{\partial u}{\partial x} = u(1-u) + f(x,t); x\in\mathbb{R}, t>0$

with initial condition $u(x,0) = g(x)$, and $f, g$ are given nonnegative functions.

I'm searching for papers to give me some clue or proposition to ensure me just the existence of a solution for this class of hyperbolic problem, but I got nothing, how can I know if there is in fact a solution given an initial condition or not? Or someone could provide me with an article I haven't gotten it yet.

Comment: This is explained in most texts that discuss first order PDEs and the method of characteristics. I would suggest Arnol'd, '_Lectures on Partial Differential Equations_', chapter 1 (if I recall correctly).

Comment: Any resource on the method of characteristics will provide such a solution. The existence and uniqueness of the solution will reduce to studying the existence and uniqueness for a related system of 3 ODEs.